# LDAP PHP Centos

Tags: php, ldap, centos

I am having strange things happen when using PHP LDAP

my username and password will authenticate correctly but if I just enter in an username with no password it also returns true.  If I type my username with the wrong password it will fail properly.  Below are the responses my code gets.

```
//Code Wrong Password
$login = ldap_bind( $ds, "Username", "WrongPass" ); 
var_dump($login);

//Response
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in /var/www/sksinternal/httpdocs/LoginCredentials.php on line 36 bool(false) 


//Code correct Password
$login = ldap_bind( $ds, "Username", "CorrectPass" ); 
var_dump($login);

//Response
bool(true)


//Code No Password
$login = ldap_bind( $ds, "Username", "" ); 
var_dump($login);

//Response
bool(true)
```

Centos 5 connecting to Windows 2008 server (Active Directory)

Comment: Does this help? http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=202622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of simple BIND:

- anonymous
- unauthenticated
- authenticated

Use of the name with zero-length password is an `unauthenticated` BIND. The LDAP standards documents state that the name is to be used for 'tracing purposes' and cannot be used for authentication, therefore, no authentication has taken place.

Modern, professional-quality servers have an option to reject unauthenticated simple BIND requests because no authentication takes place. This may not be the case with your server.